# Where does adb put installed apps on the device?

Tags: adb

Using the guide at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html, I used adb to download the sample Hello, World app to my android device (a Samsung Admire, SCH-R720) and I can't locate it to launch it.  I had the same problem with the emulator.  Where does adb put the app?  It doesn't seem to get copied to the SD card.  I've read the documentation at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html, and it doesn't say.

Comment: See related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/how-can-i-export-a-list-of-currently-installed-applications-to-a-file?amp

Answer (score 14):

Let's say you named your package `com.example.myfirstapp`. Then you can check if the package got properly installed with the following command:

```
adb shell pm list packages com.example.myfirstapp
```

If it replies with `package:com.example.myfirstapp` - then you could check the installed package location with:

```
adb shell pm path com.example.myfirstapp
```

Comment: you can also use `adb shell pm list packages -f com.example.myfirstapp` to get the full info set in one go, but be careful with the returned string -- they append '=com.example.myfirstapp' to the actual apk path

Answer (score 5):

The installed apps can be found in /data/app/

Answer (score 1):

I figure out what was going on.  I just had to cycle the power on the device.  When it rebooted, I was able to find (and launch) the app.  This worked for the emulator as well.

Answer (score 0):

The app is installed by the name of activity, have u tried locating the activity name or the app name if mentioned in manifest.
Or check the apps tab in settings and check the latest installed apps if at all it is installed on device.